# find value in array multidimen php

Tags: php, loops

I have an array like this

```
$arr = array(
    array("index"=>"5"),
    array("index"=>"7"),
);
```

wanna find value using  looping and set result like this

```
 /** OUTPUT
    '1 false'
    '2 false'
    '3 false'
    '4 false'
    '5 true'
    '6 false'
    '7 true'
 **/
```

I try my code like this, but not work

```
for($i = 1; $i <= max(array_column($arr, 'index')); $i++){
    if(in_array($i, $arr[$i]){
        echo 'true '.$i;
    }else{
        echo 'false'.$i;   
    }
}
```

thanks

Comment: You have errors in your code; you're missing a closing parenthesis in `if(in_array($i, $arr[$i]){` and `$i == max` should be `$i = max`. You were close with the general idea, though. You just need to use `array_column($arr, 'index')` instead of `$arr[$i]`.

Comment: ohh my bad.. ``$i <= max`` but output is still false if index 5 and index 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try something like:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= max(array_column($arr, 'index')); $i++) {
    if (in_array($i, array_column($arr, 'index'))) {
        echo $i . 'true' . '\n';
    } else {
        echo $i . ' false' . '\n';   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You were close to the solution but your main error was here:

```php
if(in_array($i, $arr[$i]){
```

Here you try to access the index `$i` in your original array `$arr`. That array only has two of them - 0 and 1. On the other hand, your loop will run from 1 to 7, causing "Undefined index" notices for anything greater than 1.

You seem to be familiar with the `array_column` function since you use it to determine how far your loop should go:

```php
max(array_column($arr, 'index'))
```

And this is exactly what you should compare against. This returns a simple array `[5, 7]` which can then be used as a haystack value for `in_array`:

```php
$arr = array(
    array("index"=>"5"),
    array("index"=>"7"),
);
$indices = array_column($arr, 'index'); // store it as you have to use it multiple times
for ($i = 1; $i <= max($indices); $i++) {
    if (in_array($i, $indices)) {
        var_dump('true '.$i);
    } else {
        var_dump('false '.$i);
    }
}
```

This will output:

```php
'false 1'
'false 2'
'false 3'
'false 4'
'true 5'
'false 6'
'true 7'
```